# Magento 2 Cloud Docker deployment issue

Tags: docker-compose, magento2

I am trying to set up a local environment with docker for my Magento 2 Commerce Cloud.
The containers seem to be all right.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                            NAMES
917897513a55        magento/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch:7.7-1.1   "/tini -- /usr/local…"   7 days ago          Up 3 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                               nvmcloud_elasticsearch_1
3f222162cfb0        mariadb:10.4                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 3 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32769->3306/tcp                          nvmcloud_db_1
f1393e33a973        magento/magento-cloud-docker-tls:latest-1.1          "/entrypoint.sh"         7 days ago          Up About a minute        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp                             nvmcloud_tls_1
75fd66a30fce        magento/magento-cloud-docker-varnish:latest-1.1      "/entrypoint.sh"         7 days ago          Up About a minute        80/tcp                                           nvmcloud_varnish_1
592c338aae5a        magento/magento-cloud-docker-nginx:latest-1.1        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 days ago          Up 2 minutes (healthy)   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                    nvmcloud_web_1
592f532e50c4        magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.3-fpm-1.1         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 days ago          Up 2 minutes (healthy)   9000/tcp                                         nvmcloud_fpm_1
5aa703aa8ede        redis:5.0                                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 3 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32768->6379/tcp                          nvmcloud_redis_1
5239984fe942        mailhog/mailhog:latest                               "MailHog"                7 days ago          Up About an hour         0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp   nvmcloud_mailhog_1
```

When I run `docker-compose run deploy cloud-deploy` I get this error.
`Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools returned non-zero exit status 1`
I am a newbie with docker and my research did not lead to any solution yet.
Thanks!

Comment: did u got any solution

Comment: unfortunately not yet.

Answer (score 1):

To all appearances, `ece-tools` package isn't installed yet.
Please follow Magento 2 Cloud DevDocs:

> If you still use a version of Magento Commerce Cloud that does not
> contain the `ece-tools` package, then your project requires an upgrade.
> We deprecated the `magento/magento-cloud-configuration` and
> `magento/ece-patches` packages in favor of the `ece-tools` package.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/ece-tools-upgrade-project.html

Comment: Please indicate, which Magento version are you using.

Comment: Also try these steps:  
1. Backup your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files.  
2. Prepare for update `ece-tools` by running this command:  
`composer require magento/ece-tools --no-update`  
3. Remove composer.lock file:  
`rm -rf composer.lock`  
4. Update composer dependencies by command:  
`composer update`

Reference: https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/developing-on-the-magento-cloud-a-step-by-step-tutorial (Step 3)